# Why is the SOAP Webservice error returned by the service provider?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, webservice-client

I'm using a `SOAP` `web-service` developed by `webservicex` server (downloaded from [here](http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?wsdl)) to develop a country locator application with IP address as input. Imported the jar files and java files, using the `wsimport`. Now, developed a java application that returns the country name by taking the input as IP address. Everything was working as per plan, without any syntax errors.

But when executing the java program, it returned an error which I couldn't trace back(I'm a learner). I'm not sure if it is a problem with either `WS` or `Jar` files.

The error is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at WebserviceX.Service.Adapter.IPAdapter.CheckIP(String IP)
   at WebserviceX.Service.GeoIPService.GetGeoIP(String IPAddress)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:238)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.getGeoIP(Unknown Source)
    at org.giri.soap.IPcountryFinder.main(IPcountryFinder.java:20)
```

Can someone shed some light on why this error occurs, am I missing from normal steps in executing the program.

Is this some an error returned by the `web-service` provider? If so, should I contact the service provider?

Comment: I had the same issue, I suppose it might be a problem with webservice provider. But still, not sure...

Comment: Looks like a `.net` error, so this is not coming from your code. It's essentially a null pointer exception. Make sure that your making the call properly. If the problem persists you'll need to contact the service provider.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the method call is good. I can say this because I don't find any errors with my code, I mean syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not in the code it's with the webservice provider. if you go to the link http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?op=GetGeoIP
and pass Ip address you will get the same error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it works with limited number of ip addresses. For example, for me it works with IPs of bbc.com, google.com, but it doesn't work with facebook.com.